# Can't install Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-studio

When trying to install Visual Studio the installer won't show any text. There is an icon in the taskbar, but there's not any progress. As I researched one solution was .NET Framework reinstall. I reinstalled it, but it was still the same.

I have Windows 7 32-bit on VirtualBox. I tried Visual Studio 2012, 2015 and 2017, but it was the same on all of them. It gets stuck like this every time.

[image: ---]

Comment: Make sure the virtual machine can access the physical machine via the network: it is recommended to set the network adapter settings in the VM to NAT. If you encounter connection problems later, check your firewall settings. Source: http://sysprogs.com/legacy/articles/visualddk/firstdriver/

Comment: yes but i have offline installer

Comment: That's good, but it still phones home a lot.